# byte[] and char[] on NetBeans Profiler

Tags: java, netbeans, profiling, profiler

I'm running NetBeans Profiler in my application and byte[] and char[] occupy approximately 90% of the memory allocated. My entity, beans, service, etc., don't occupy 2%.

Do you know why or it can be some NetBeans Profiler's mistake?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not familiar with netbeans profiler, so I won't make this an answer, but what you are seeing is probably correct: your beans and services themselves take up very little memory, but they will reference other objects (e.g. Strings) which ultimately store their contents in byte[] and char[] objects. See if you can ask the profiler to show you the size of an object *including* objects it references.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a mistake, since the underlying object is `char[]` or `byte[]` in many case. For example - the size of a `String` object will be shown as very small even for large `String`s, as the `String` object actually contains a `char[]`, who is the actual big allocation.

Take a look at the [OpenJDK implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java). Not a big object at all, but contains a possibly huge `char[]`.

Comment: So, I think it's impossible to reduce my application's memory consumption, right?